# Passing ext textbox values to javascript and then to controller action

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, controller

I have a scenario where I have to pass the username and password values from ext textfield to a controller action to do validation with the database. I have written the following code

```
   <ext:TextField Name="Username" runat="server" ID="UserName"></ext:TextField>
   <ext:TextField Name="Password" runat="server" ID="Password"></ext:TextField>
   <ext:Button runat="server" ID="submit1" Type="Submit"  Text="LOGIN" >
    <Listeners>
        <Click Fn="CallLogin">

        </Click>
    </Listeners>

    </ext:Button>
```

function CallLogin() {

```
        var username = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('Password').value;

        //var url = '@Url.Action("Login", "Index")';
        //window.location.href = url;

        window.location.href = '/Login/Index/';          

                   }
```

How do i pass these values to the controller action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use ajax and jquery to achieve this.

1.Include jquery library in your page header

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</head>
```

2.Perform the ajax call in CallLogin() functoin

```
function CallLogin() {
        var username = document.getElementById('UserName').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('Password').value;

  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Login/Index/',
                    data: { userText: username , passwordText: password },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response > 0) {
                           alert("Success");
                          }
                        else
                         {
                        alert("Login failed");
                           }

    });

}
```

Assuming you action method looks something like this:

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public int Index(string userText, string passwordText)
        {

           return (checkValidUser(userText,passwordText));
        }
```

Comment: Hi slacker..thank you for your reply..however when i tried your code..the button is not submitting to the controller..as such the page does not submit.. When i try the same in IE browser..it shoots an error saying $ is undeclared.. any idea why?

Comment: You need to include jquery library in your page to make it work. See my modified answer

Comment: <script  lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion-common/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/accordion-common/jquery.msAccordion.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                                  I have added the following code to my aspx file..however the code is working as expected only in mozilla

Comment: download latest version of jquery library and provide its path instead of `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: You have included two different versions of jquery. Remove one

Comment: ok it Works! why am i not able to pass a third parameter along with username and password...that value is a date and its always coming as null..